# How to print multiple indexes from a list with brackets around it?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I am trying to solve a simple leetcode problem, and my code can output the right answer but not in the correct format. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:

    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        list2 = []
        for x in nums:
            for y in nums:
                if x + y == target:
                    list2.append(x)
                    print(nums.index(x))
```

For the input of:

```
[2,7,11,15]
9
```

My code is outputting

```
0
1
```

When it should be outputting

```
[0,1]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `list2`?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Even though you could *fix* the code, it won't pass the timing test - it's O(n**2)  Try to think hashmap - dictionary way.  (O(n)) is the goal...

Comment: @PeterWood sorry, that was for an idea i had to produce the right answer.  It seems that the response from azro utilized it in the fix. Thank you

Comment: @DanielHao Thanks for your reply. I will try to learn how to solve the problem in that way, right now as a superbeginner it sounds very intimidating but I understand that is the eventual goal

Comment: That's great - *brute force* is the beginning, as long as you got it. Optimize can always comes later.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the index, save it

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        list2 = []
        for x in nums:
            for y in nums:
                if x + y == target:
                    list2.append(nums.index(x))
        return list2

print(Solution().twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))  # [0, 1]
```

---

But instead of iterating the second, just look for the possible complement to the target

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        list2 = []
        for x in nums:
            possible_y = target - x
            if possible_y in nums:
                list2.append(nums.index(x))
        return list2
```